# Alternate Character arrangement using java

Tags: java, string

```
public class Main {
    public static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "AAAA";
        System.out.println(delete1(str));;
    }

    private static int delete1(String str) {
        if (str.length() > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if (str.charAt(i-1) == str.charAt(i)) {
                    count++;
                    str = str.substring(i, str.length());
                    delete1(str);
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

}
```

count should come as 3 in this case...but coming as 4

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Your "delete" method really does count char by looping on them name it correctly. Additionnaly, the loop is bad coded, both recursive and iterative, with a global count. just remove the recursion, declare count in the method.

Comment: I am trying to remove alternate character and counting no of character to be removed. for example if AAB o/p shud be 1...since only 1 will be removed so that no repeating characters

Comment: May be coding is poor and might be better ways are there to do this..but i need to know why this is not wrking..loop goes perfect till 3 after that it comes back to recursive call...which i am not getting

Comment: When your program runs but does not produce the result you expect and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging.  Help yourself to some free debugging tips [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) if you need some suggestions on how to get started.

Comment: What is the expected output with input `AAAABABBAB` or `ABAAAAABBABA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loop inside recursive method does not have break statement. put break; statement after delete1(str); statement will work.

```
delete1(str);
break;
```

while using recursive you should know where to break the loop and how functional flow happens in java.

in your case for all sub strings of length more than 2 will call delete method more than once. that's why you got output as 4.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code:

1. You have the `count` on class-level and also let your method return this count.
2. You continue your loop after your recursive call
3. Not really wrong, but your `if(str.length() > 1)` check is redundant since your loop is already looping in the range `[1, length)`, so the loop wouldn't start anyway if the length is smaller than or equal to 1.

Keeping the things above in mind, you could change it to this:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "AAAA"; // Expected output: 3
    countChars(str);
    System.out.println(count);
  }

  private static int count = 0;
  private static void countChars(String str){
    int length = str.length();
    for(int i = 1; i < length; i++){
      if(str.charAt(i-1) == str.charAt(i)){
        count++;
        String substr = str.substring(i, length);
        countChars(substr);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which puts the `count` at 3 in the end as you expected.

[**Try it online.**](https://ideone.com/YST01c)

I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish however. For example, what would the expected output be for `AAAABABBAB` or `ABAAAAABBABA`? Also, it would be better if the count isn't a static class-level field so it can more easily be re-used.